# Test case different type

Tags: unit-test

I have a test case and i am having trouble running it. It is telling me that i have 2 different type and i am not sure how to fix it. Any one has any idea?
Thanks in advance.

```
    testMethod private static void testCreateAccount(){
    Account act = TestDataFactory.BuildAccount('Recruter');

    insert act;
    Account  actCon = [SELECT Name, BillingAddress, AccountNumber From Account ];
    Contact  cont =[SELECT Name, Address__c,AccountId From Contact WHERE AccountId = :actCon.AccountNumber];

   System.assertEquals(actCon.BillingAddress, actCon.Address__c);
}
```

Comment: Try `WHERE AccountId = :actCon.Id` so both values are Id values.

Comment: i think  this issue is that assert equal does not compare diffrent types

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the error you are getting is the:

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types

Since the Standard Account Address field is a compound address field and I am assuming the custom address__c field is not since you cannot create a custom compound field, this is why you are getting the error. Without knowing what is in the custom address__c field I can only assume it might be equivalent to BillingStreet vs. BillingAddress. Also, as Keith mentioned you will want to use the actCon.Id to filter your contacts Query not the AccountNumber field.